# How to specify fields when there are keywords in the field list in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to parse some historical SQL in the high version of hive (version is 2.3.7) so that tasks can be migrated to the high version. I encountered the following keyword problem. I cannot delete the field list after the table name because it may disrupt the insertion order.

**How to deal with such a keyword problem? The field name of the old version of SQL cannot be changed**

```
hive> create database db_test;
OK
Time taken: 0.017 seconds
hive> use db_test;
OK
Time taken: 0.007 seconds
hive> create table tb_test_to(
    >     `name` String,
    >     `interval` STRING
    > );
OK
Time taken: 0.037 seconds
hive> create table tb_test_from(
    >     `name` String,
    >     `interval` STRING
    > );
OK
Time taken: 0.052 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
tb_test_from
tb_test_to
Time taken: 0.011 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> insert into tb_test_to (name,`interval`) select name, `interval` from tb_test_from;
FAILED: SemanticException 1:24 '`interval`' in insert schema specification is not found among regular columns of db_test.tb_test_to nor dynamic partition columns.. Error encountered near token '`interval`'
hive>
```

[image]

Comment: Backticks are missing in the `name` on your `insert into ... ` line of code

Answer (score 0):

You can only do

```
insert into tb_test_to select name, `interval` from tb_test_from;
```

because you cannot specify a column list in HiveQL queries, according to the HiveQL manual at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Synopsis.3

> Values must be provided for every column in the table. The standard SQL syntax that allows the user to insert values into only some columns is not yet supported. To mimic the standard SQL, nulls can be provided for columns the user does not wish to assign a value to.

Comment: if change `interval` to `interval2` to avoid keyword, it will success. So I think Hive support this syntax.

Comment: create table tb_test_to2(
    name String,
    interval2 STRING
);


create table tb_test_from2(
    name String,
    interval2 STRING
);

insert into tb_test_to2 (interval2) select interval2 from tb_test_from2;

Comment: `insert into tb_test_to2 (interval2) select interval2 from tb_test_from2;` doesn't work for me. It gives the same error as you've shown in the question.

Comment: it run succ on my vmware machine.

Comment: @Z.Lun could you show a screenshot? that's very strange because it shouldn't work according to the docs and doesn't work on my machine

Comment: I will add screeshot in this question